# Apache2: Allow directory indexing, but restrict file access by type

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, configuration, access-control-list, directoryindex

I need to configure my Apache2 server (version 2.2.22) such that I allow auto-indexing of the WWW root folder and its sub-directories, but restrict access (i.e. restrict download) to just a set of specific file types (i.e. .txt and .log).  In other words, anybody can see what files are present, but only certain file types can be downloaded.

I have come up with the following which does restrict download to just the specified file types, but all URLs for a directory index return 403 Forbidden.

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    <FilesMatch "">
        Order deny,allow
        allow from all
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch ".+\.(?!(txt|log)$)[^\.]+?$">
        Order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </FilesMatch>
</Directory>
```

Comment: Regexp seems to be weird. Did you try something like `.+\.(txt|log)$`? This one `FilesMatch ""` seems to be useless here.

Comment: @Glueon, giving the order he's set it's needed to permit listing at all.

Comment: Keith, since accessing the directory doesn't match any of the file extensions you've specified Apache is not serving the directory listing.  I played around with this configuration for a bit, but couldn't get it to work.  You'll most likely have to ditch FilesMatch and use mod_rewrite instead.

Comment: Listing files that can't be downloaded seems a bit counterintuitive, why not use the [IndexIgnore](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_autoindex.html#indexignore) Directive to only list directories and .txt and .log files?

Answer (score 4):

You need also to allow index files:

```
<FilesMatch "^index\.">
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

because Apache will search for them (like `index.html`, `index.cgi`,...) but they are all forbidden. I'm not sure why, but I suppose Apache cannot even check for existence of those files, and then sends a 403.
If Apache can check the inexistence of those index files, he will create the directory index, and that needs the `<FilesMatch "">` Directive, as the index file name is "".

You can find the information in the error logfile, some lines like:

```
client denied by server configuration: /var/www/index.html
```

And because you want that forbidden files are listed too, you need to add:

```
IndexOptions ShowForbidden
```

for example after `Options Indexes FollowSymLinks`.
There are plenty of options for directory indexes you can find them in the [apache doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/fr/mod/mod_autoindex.html#indexoptions).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The `FilesMatch` needs to hit every possible entry from the `DirectoryIndex` directive and the empty string. If you have this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.html.var index.php
```

then this is your match:

`<Files ~ ^index\.(html|php|html.var)$|^$>`

It might be easiest to set `DirectoryIndex` and then match:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
<Files ~ ^index\.html$|^$>
    <Limit GET HEAD>
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
    </Limit>
</Files>
```

Comment: [Apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html) recommend switching to require. You should probably add at least the OPTIONS method to the limit, but really I don't see any harm in allowing any method, so I'm wondering why the restriction.